Attribute must be declared and The content of element type must match
I have been trying to figure out how to start my weblogic server with my servlet project with maven for three days, but I find that it is giving me errors with the web.xml. I have a colleague who doesn't have this problem in his IDE, but it does for me and I can't find the solution.
This is my web.xml:
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

  <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
           id="WebApp_ID"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>consultCupon202006</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Promotion</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Promotion</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.consultcupon202006.servlet.Promotion</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Promotion</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Promotion</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Mainly the errors it shows me are due to the attributes and the web-app, but even when changing the version or order I still get the same errors:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "web-app".
Attribute "xsi:schemaLocation" must be declared for element type "web-app".
Content is not allowed in prolog.
Attribute "xmlns" must be declared for element type "web-app".
The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display-      name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servlet-

mapping*,session-config?,mime-mapping*,welcome-file-list?,error-page*,taglib*,resource-env-ref*,resource-
ref*,security-constraint*,login-config?,security-role*,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*)".

Attribute "version" must be declared for element type "web-app".


I have edited the web.xml with the changes, but it still gives me another error:
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>consultCupon202006</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Promotion</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Promotion</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.test.consultcupon202006.servlet.Promotion</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Promotion</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Promotion</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>


The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type
declaration must be well-formed.

I have also changed the version of the dependency to:
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Any advice or help would help me shed some light on this.

You are referring to both the 2.3 DTD and the 3.1 schema. Pick one.

I have the same error

The schema web-app_3_1.xsd contains errors.

I have changed it, but I still have errors, could you explain a little more please?

The content of element type "web-app" must match "(icon?,display- name?,description?,distributable?,context-param*,filter*,filter-mapping*,listener*,servlet*,servle...  is about the order of those children, because of the parentheses around them and the lack of any multipliers around the parentheses. Your welcome-file list should come after all the servlet declarations and mappings.
If you're going to have description elements, which aren't required, you should have content in them.

I use eclipse 2020-06 due to weblogic versions and if I put it as you mentioned it gives me this error: content is not allowed in trailing section web.xml webapp, but if I put the change in my eclipse with the most recent version it doesn't no error occurs. What could it be ?

Without seeing the entire updated content, it's hard to say, but there shouldn't be anything in the file after the web-app end tag.
